# Сайт ломается после добавления формы капчи в вид

Tags: php, kohana, captcha

Сайт ломается, пишет:

> "страница недоступна" на всех страницах сайта

после добавления формы капчи в вид.

Мои действия по добавлению модуля капчи на сайт:

1 Распаковал модуль в `modules/captcha`.

2 Заменил старый вариант вызова request:

```
Request::instance()->headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/'.$this->image_type;
Request::instance()->headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0';
Request::instance()->headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
Request::instance()->headers['Connection'] = 'close';
```

на новый

```
Request::current()->headers('Content-Type', 'image/'.$this->image_type);
Request::current()->headers('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
Request::current()->headers('Pragma', 'no-cache');
Request::current()->headers('Connection', 'close');
```

3 Подключил модуль в `bootstrap.php`:

```
 Kohana::modules(array(
    //  'debug-toolbar' => MODPATH . 'debug-toolbar', // Basic authentication
        'auth'          => MODPATH . 'auth', // Basic authentication
        'admin'         => MODPATH . 'admin', // administration module
        'cache'         => MODPATH . 'cache', // Caching with multiple backends
        'static-files'  => MODPATH . 'static-files', // Caching with multiple backends
        'database'      => MODPATH . 'database', // Database access
        'image'         => MODPATH . 'image', // Image manipulation
        'captcha'      => MODPATH .  'captcha',  // Captcha
        'orm'           => MODPATH . 'orm', // Object Relationship Mapping
        'I18n_Plural'   => MODPATH . 'I18n_Plural', // I18n Plural
    ));
```

4 Создал контроллер `MainCaptcha.php` в `application/classes/controller`:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_MainCaptcha extends Controller_Template {    

    public $template = 'main_page';
    protected $path, $cur_elem;

    public function action_index()
    {
        if($post = $this->request->post()){
            /** Проверяем Каптчу на валидацию */
            if(Captcha::valid($post['captcha'])){
                // записываем данные в БД, например
            }
        }
        $captcha_image = Captcha::instance()->render();
        // выводим наш шаблон
        $this->template->content = View::factory('MainCaptcha')->bind('captcha_image', $captcha_image);
    }
```

5 В виде в файле `main_page.php` прописываю форму капчи и после этого сайт ломается, а если убираю форму, сайт работает:

```
<form id="goToQuim" method="post" action="/ajax/question">
                            <label>
                                <input class="inputStyle" required type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Ваше имя...">
                            </label>
                            <label>
                                <input class="inputStyle" required type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="E-mail...">
                            </label>
                            <label>
                                <textarea class="inputStyle" required name="question" placeholder="Ваш вопрос..."></textarea>
                            </label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="agree" style="width:20px;"><a href="/politika_konfidencialnosti" target="_blank">Я прочитал и согласен с Пользовательским соглашением</a>
                                              <?php echo $captcha; ?>
       <label>Введите код указанный на картинке:</label>
        <?=Form::input('captcha')?>
        <?=$captcha_image?>
       <img alt="Обновить код" src="uploads/images/refresh.png" class="refresh" title="Обновить код" />

                            <label class="labelbtn"><input class="btnStyle continue" type="submit" value="Отправить"></label>

                        </form>
```

Может я что-то делаю не так или что-то упустил?